# Almost, but not quite a trapping region

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for a term for something that almost fits the definition of a trapping region. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapping_region), a set is a trapping region for a dynamical system if every trajectory which starts within the set will move to the region's **interior**, and will remain there as the system evolves.

I've proved that a closed set I'm working with almost fits this definition: trajectories which start in the set remain in the set as the system evolves, but they may remain on the boundary of the set, rather than moving to the interior. Is there a term for this? Is the term trapping region sometimes used in this way?

Comment: One purpose of trapping regions (in 2D) is to show that a limit cycle must exist. By showing that the trajectory becomes "trapped" without any fixed points in that region implies a periodic orbit ([Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré–Bendixson_theorem)). It sounds like you've just happen to find the periodic orbit in this case. I don't believe there is another name for this trajectory (maybe limit cycle?)

Comment: I'm actually not constructing this region to find a limit cycle using Poincare-Bendixon, it's useful as part of a completely different argument. I'm just curious whether there's a word for this sort of region.

Comment: I guess I am confused then. What happens to the trajectories in the interior of the trapping region?

Comment: They stay in the interior. (I'm really just asking a terminology question, not a math question. But likely the answer is that there's no word for the thing I'm asking about, since no one else has had a reason to care about it.)

Comment: Where do they go? Is this a 2D dynamical system? They must go to a point? It does not sound like a trapping region.

If points outside the boundary tend to the boundary and points inside tend towards a point (or at least are repelled from the boundary), you have described a saddle limit cycle.

Comment: Oh, I'm thinking about a family of dynamical systems in arbitrary dimension. Some systems in the family have trajectories that go to fixed points on the boundary of this region or inside it, some have limit cycles, some have chaos, etc. It's just useful as part of another argument to constrain trajectories to a subset of phase space.

Comment: But the key point is that what you are calling a "trapping region" behaves based on how you described as a saddle cycle. Inside this region you move away and outside you move towards. This is the closest thing I can think of that you're describing.

Comment: Ok. I don't think that's quite right either. It's useful to know there isn't a common word for this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a **forward invariant set** or **positively invariant set**.

(The condition is that solutions starting in the set stay in the set for all $t \ge 0$. This includes actually being defined for all $t\ge 0$, in contrast to blowing up after finite time; if the set is compact, this detail is nothing to worry about.)

Comment: You may also wish to look into the _viability kernel_ (which is a set, despite the confusing name), which closely related to the forward invariant set.